# How to find 1/3 and 2/3 of the distance between two given points?

Tags: unity, mathematics

I know how to find the middle of two given points:

```
var midpoint = (pointA + pointB)/2;
```

where `pointA` and `pointB` are `Vector2`

I thought that

```
var thirdBtnPoints = (pointA + pointB)/3;
var twoThirdBtnPoints = 2*(pointA + pointB)/3;
```

should give me 1/3 and 2/3 between the two points but it doesn't. I guess this might be more of a math question though, but how can I find 1/3 and 2/3 of the distance between two given points?

Comment: I can see only integer divisions. Try typecasting pointA and/or pointB to floating point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let A and B be the two points. The formula looks like this:

```
desiredPoint = A +(B-A) *2/3;
```

Replace `2/3` by your desired fraction. This counts from point `A`, so `2/3` means the resulting point will be closer to point `B`.

The explanation is simple. You take point `A`, then move towards `B` (`+(B-A)`), and multiply that by how long towards `B` to move (`*2/3`).

Since you are using Unity, you can use its own function `Lerp`: (Thanks @DMGregory)

```
Vector3 desiredPoint = Vector3.Lerp(A, B, 2f/3f);
```

This basically gives the same result as the explanation above.